# How to implement a while loop in Python?

Tags: python, list, printing, while-loop

Basically I need to write a program that takes input from a user and stores it in a list over and again until the word "end" is passed.

**Sample Input**

```
Spanish
dog
bowl
end
```

**Sample Output**

```
['spanish', 'dog', 'bowl']
```

This is what I have so far:

```
a = []
index = 0
i = 1
while i != 0:
    s = raw_input()
    if s == "end":
        i = 0
    else:
        a[index] = s
        index = index + 1
print (a)
```

Note that as part of the assignment, a while loop **must** be used.

Comment: Do you really need all the commentary about the teacher to ask this question?

Comment: Perhaps doing [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) might help ?

Comment: I suppose i didn't need to include that no, my bad. Just in a bit of a hurry so wasn't thinking. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
words = []
while True:
    word = input()
    if word == 'end':
        break
    else:
        words.append(word)
print(words)
```

Example

```
Spanish
dog
bowl
end
['Spanish', 'dog', 'bowl']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 3.8+, you can use this cool new feature called [*assignment expressions*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) like so:

```
lst = []
while (answer := input('item (type "end" to exit): \t')) != 'end':
    lst.append(answer)
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you like one-line solution:

```
from itertools import takewhile, cycle

words = list(takewhile(lambda x: x != 'end', map(input, cycle(['type your item: ']))))
```

or:

```
words = list(takewhile(lambda x: x != 'end', map(input, cycle(['']))))
print(words)
```

output:

```
Spanish
dog
bowl
end
['Spanish', 'dog', 'bowl']
```